# Get File size in hex using forfiles

Tags: windows, cmd, forfiles

I am using this command in CMD to take all file size in a directory.

```
forfiles /s /c "cmd /c echo @file @fsize" >filelist.txt
```

There has someway to take this size but in hex format?

Example:

> ```
> "00000000.png" 219457
> ```

to

> ```
> "00000000.png" 50A6E
> ```

Comment: If you type `forfiles /?` at a command prompt, you can see what it supports (and by inference, what it doesn't).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While this does not use `FORFILES`, it can be used in a `windows` `cmd` `batch-file`. Since this is a recursive search, I assume you would want the fully qualified path included to avoid problems when the same filename is used in multiple directories.

```
powershell -NoLogo -NoProfile -Command ^
    "$q='\"';Get-ChildItem -File -Recurse ^| ForEach-Object {$($q+$_.FullName+$q) + ' ' + $($_.Length.ToString('X'))}"
```

Comment: How about, here --------- powershell "gci | sort @{Expression={[int][RegEx]::Match($_, '\d+').Value}} | %%{ $_.Name } | Select-Object -Skip 1" > Headerlist.txt

I am saving name of files in a folder and sort by natural expression, can i convert them to hex as well?

Comment: @ThiagoMartinsdossantos, I am not sure what your code does. The output of `gci` is an object with members. What are you expecting the result of the `regex` match to be? Does the code I provided work for you?

Comment: yes!, work very well thks, somehow my reply was deleted.
this is another doubt.
this code above take file name in a folder and put in txt, but in expression order.

like 
0
130
300
500
560
I want to convert those decimal in hex.

Comment: Are you saying that you want the output to be sorted by file size? Or, are you saying that there are numbers in the filename that should be used for sorting. Numbers in the filename was not part of the original question.

Comment: Sorry, maybe i should open another section of question.
Your help code, works super well to me!, but now i am in another problem.
i have a bunch of files that have filename as decimal, like 0 100, 200, 344, etc
so i used this code powershell "gci | sort @{Expression={[int][RegEx]::Match($_, '\d+').Value}} | %%{ $_.Name } | Select-Object -Skip 1" > Headerlist.txt, to take the filename as by expression order, works perctcly, but how can i convert them to hex, like you did in the size? thanks

Comment: Yes, this should be a different question. Please create a new one.

Answer (score 0):

Well, [`forfiles`](https://ss64.com/nt/forfiles.html) does certainly not support to convert decimal to hexadecimal numbers.

Converting numbers in pure conventional batch scripting is not natively supported, so you will have to either borrow from another language (like PowerShell, VBScript, JavaScript, all of which are supplied with a modern Windows system), or to code it yourself the hard way (step by step as if you would do it on paper).

Anyway, luckily there is a hidden and undocumented dynamic pseudo-variable called [`=ExitCode`](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-variables.html), which holds the hexadecimal value of the most recent [exit code](https://ss64.com/nt/errorlevel.html), which we can make use of:

```cmd
rem // Iterate through all files in the current working directory:
for /R %%I in (*.*) do (
    rem // Store name of currently iterated item:
    set "ITEM=%%~I"
    rem // Toggle delayed expansion to avoid issues with `!` and `^`:
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    rem // Explicitly set exit code to the size of the current file:
    cmd /C exit 0%%~zI
    rem // Return the exit code, hence the file size, as hex number:
    echo(!ITEM!  !=ExitCode!
    endlocal
)
```

Note, that files must be less than 2 GiB in size, because exit codes are given as signed 32-bit integers.

Comment: Thank you! it worked very well.
i did some alteration to my needs, and worked very well.
i did not know about exitcode. nice to know!

try to upvote but my reputation is newbie to that,

Comment: You're welcome! You can (after a while) accept the answer you liked most (by the green checkmark)…